# Unable to set query parameters manually for a rest api (using mux)

Tags: go, mux

I am implementing a Rest api using mux. After validating some parameters, I am trying to fill the missing parameters with some default values which I process later by the method that handles the request, however, I noticed that setting query parameters manually does not have any effect, unless the raw query is directly changed which is a bit hacky:

```
func ValidateParameters(r *http.Request) (bool) {

     test := r.URL.Query().Get("test")

   // if test is not provided set some default value

    if test == "" {

        r.URL.Query().Set("test", "Test1") //not working
        r.URL.Query().Add("test", "Test2") //not working
        r.URL.RawQuery = r.URL.RawQuery + "&Test=Test3" // the only method working

     }

       // more code

}
```

The handler is in another file, so I want to be able to do `test := r.URL.Query().Get("test")` and get the value that I set inside `ValidateParameters` which is called by the request handler, but this is not working.

any explanation to that ? any way to work around it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with net/url.Values.Encode() ?

Comment: not sure I follow ? sorry maybe my question is not clear enough

Comment: I hope it is clearer with new edit. In short, I want to manually add query parameters in the validation phase before starting to handle the request, which is done in another `function` that calls `ValidateParameters()`, but it is does not have any effect.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted, it could help somebody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `r.URL.Query()` parses the url, creates the map of parameters and returns it. This is done with every `.Query()` call.

This should work:

```
params := r.URL.Query()
params.Set("key", "value")
r.URL.RawQuery = params.Encode()
```